# Dispose should not be called on this object. // SPDisposeCheck comment

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, spweb, spdisposechecker, memory-leak

In the code below, within `using` directive, for `rootweb`, `Dispose();` method will be called implicitly, is that correct? Or should I need a `using` directive for this: `SPWeb rootweb = site.RootWeb` since I am not using `new` keyword?

The reason I am asking because `SPDisposeCheck` gives following comments:

> Dispose should not be called on this object.
>
> Initial Assignment: rootweb := site.
>
> {Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite}get_RootWeb()

```
public override void FeatureActivated(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
        {
            var site = properties.Feature.Parent as SPSite;
            if (site != null)
            {
                
                AddTaxonomyField(site);
            }
        }

private void AddTaxonomyField(SPSite site)
{
    SPContextManager.Current.LogManager.LogInformationToDevelopers(String.Format("Adding {0} to {1}.", CorCatColumn, site.Url));
    try
    {
        using (SPWeb rootweb = site.RootWeb) // At this line
        {
            if (!rootweb.Fields.ContainsField(CorCatColumn))
            {
                TaxonomySession session = new TaxonomySession(site);
                TermStore ts = session.DefaultSiteCollectionTermStore;
                if (session.TermStores.Count != 0)
                {
                   string taxonomyField = "SomeField";
                   string noteField = "SomeField";
                   rootweb.Fields.AddFieldAsXml(noteField);
                   rootweb.Update();
                   rootweb.Fields.AddFieldAsXml(taxonomyField);
                   rootweb.Update();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        SPContextManager.Current.LogManager.LogErrorToDevelopers(ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you get the SPSite you pass into AddTaxonomyField?

Comment: @Jussi, I have updated my question, SPSite is coming from FeatureActivated() method, Whats your comments now?

Comment: Updated the end of my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not explicitly (or via using) call `Dispose()` on the `SPSite.RootWeb` property.  The dispose cleanup will be handled automatically by the SharePoint and the .NET framework.

For existing SharePoint customizations removal of explicit RootWeb Dispose is recommended to avoid an edge case condition where the `SPContext.Current.Web` has equality to the `SPSite.RootWeb`.

Problems can occur when disposing `RootWeb` when obtained from any variation of `SPContext` (e.g., `SPContext.Site.RootWeb`, `SPContext.Current.Site.RootWeb` and `GetContextSite(Context).RootWeb`). **Note the owning `SPSite` object must be properly disposed (or *not* disposed in the case of `SPContext`).**

So in you case, just do like this:

```
private void AddTaxonomyField(SPSite site)
{
    SPContextManager.Current.LogManager.LogInformationToDevelopers(String.Format("Adding {0} to {1}.", CorCatColumn, site.Url));
    try
    {
        SPWeb rootweb = site.RootWeb
        //...
```

But make sure you dispose the `SPSite` you pass into the `AddTaxonomyField` in the function that calls `AddTaxonomyField` UNLESS you take it from `SPContext`. As you get it from `properties.Feature.Parent`, you should not Dispose it, so I'd just do the above mentioned change.

[Source](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rogerla/archive/2008/10/04/updated-spsite-rootweb-dispose-guidance.aspx) and [Source](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/c0f1a05f-f1db-4f37-8f24-5966ab43e73b/dispose-spweb-object-inside-feature-receiver-or-dont?forum=sharepointdevelopmentlegacy)

Comment: Thanks!!! that removes my confusion and helped me lot---

Answer (score 1):

The code is wrong. You need to use `using` directive only with objects that you created yourself. The code would be correct in this case:

```
private void AddTaxonomyField(SPSite site)
{
    using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb()) //need "using" because you opened the SPWeb yourself
    {

    }
}
```

This code would dispose of the web object at the end of using statement.
This would be correct as well:

```
private void AddTaxonomyField(SPSite site)
{
    var rootWeb = site.RootWeb; // no need for "using" since the object is managed by SPSite.
}
```

In your example, you haven't opened a new web but instead you used `SPSite.RootWeb` object (and `SPSite` will take care of that for you). Since the `SPSite.RootWeb` wasn't opened (or created in simple terms) by you - therefor there is no need to use `using` or call `.Dispose()`.

I believe this is your third similar question in a row :) Just note the following guidelines and it might help:

1. using = automatic dispose;
2. You don't dispose of something you don't own (create);

Comment: You can't be sure `.OpenWeb()` will actually open the root web; it depends on how the `SPSite` had been created first. Also, why opening explicitely (which brings a performance cost), while the root web of an `SPSite` may already have opened (and kept) the `.RootWeb` property?

Comment: The site.OpenWeb() is just an example. And I am not advising on opening the webs :) I just wanted to make clear that OP needs "using" keyword when creating objects by himself. Sorry for confusion. I renamed rootWeb to web, just so it's more clear.